# Recyclerview OnScroll down, layout getting hide which opened on button click

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-adapter, onscrolllistener

I am using recyclerview, in my list item I have button. On that button click I am hiding and showing imageview, now if user click on list item and open imageview and then scrolldown and scrollup, the item in which user opened imageview is getting closed. This is my adapter code:

```
public class NotiDetailsListAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotiDetailsListAdapter.ViewHolder> {
        Context context;
        private List<NotificationListData> adaBankDetailsList;
        String bnkName = "", bnkAccNum = "", userName = "", bankIfscCode = "", bankType = "";
        private int selectedPosition = -1;
        boolean flag = true;

        private NotiDetailsListAdapter(Context conytext, List<NotificationListData> bankDetails) {
            this.context = conytext;
            this.adaBankDetailsList = bankDetails;
        }

        @NonNull
        @Override
        public NotiDetailsListAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            View view;
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.notification_list_item_layout, parent, false);
            return new NotiDetailsListAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
        }

        @Override
        public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final NotiDetailsListAdapter.ViewHolder holder, int pos) {
             bnkResponse = adaBankDetailsList.get(pos);

            try {


                holder.notification_main_text.setText(bnkResponse.getNotificationTitle());
                holder.notification_sub_text.setText(bnkResponse.getNotificationMessage());



                String mydates=bnkResponse.getNotificationSendTime();
                String[] str_array1 = mydates.split("-");

                if(str_array1[0] != null && str_array1[0].length() > 0 && str_array1[1] != null && str_array1[1].length() > 0) {

                    stringa1 = str_array1[0];
                    stringb1 = str_array1[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    stringa1 = str_array1[0];
                    stringb1 = "";
                }



                String[] timearray = stringb1.split(":");
                if(timearray[0] != null && timearray[0].length() > 0 && timearray[1] != null && timearray[1].length() > 0) {

                    stringt1 = timearray[0];
                    stringt2 = timearray[1];
                }
                else
                {
                    stringt1 = timearray[0];
                    stringt2 = "";
                }
                if(mydates.contains("PM"))
                {
                    stringampm="PM";
                }
                else if(mydates.contains("AM"))
                {
                    stringampm="AM";
                }




                System.out.println("Dates "+stringampm+" "+stringt2);
                holder.notification_date.setText(stringa1);
                holder.notification_time.setText(stringt1+":"+stringt2+" "+stringampm);
                holder.notification_iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                holder.notification_main_text.setSingleLine(false);
                holder.notification_main_text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                int n1 = 1; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                holder.notification_main_text.setLines(n1);
                holder.notification_main_text.setMaxEms(12);

                holder.notification_sub_text.setSingleLine(false);
                holder.notification_sub_text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                int n = 1; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                holder.notification_sub_text.setLines(n);
                holder.iv_arrow.setImageResource(R.mipmap.down);



            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }


        @Override
        public int getItemCount() {
            return adaBankDetailsList.size();
        }

        public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder  implements View.OnClickListener {
            TextView notification_main_text, notification_sub_text, notification_date, notification_time;
            ImageView iv_arrow,notification_iv;
            RelativeLayout parentRL,notification_rl;
            LinearLayout arrow_click;

            public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
                super(itemView);
                notification_main_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_main_text);
                notification_sub_text = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_sub_text);
                notification_date = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_date);
                notification_time = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_time);
                iv_arrow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_arrow);
                notification_iv = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_iv);
                parentRL = itemView.findViewById(R.id.parentRL);
                notification_rl = itemView.findViewById(R.id.notification_rl);
                arrow_click = itemView.findViewById(R.id.arrow_click);
                // Store the context

                // Attach a click listener to the entire row view

                parentRL.setOnClickListener(this);
                iv_arrow.setOnClickListener(this);
               /* itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View view) {

                    }
                });*/


            }


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                int position = getAdapterPosition();
                switch (view.getId()){

                    case R.id.parentRL:
                        try {

                            if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("promotion")) {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, InviteEarnWebViewActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                //notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId",(bnkResponse.getLevelId()));
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("searchQuery", adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getCustomPageUrl());
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("headerName", adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getCustomPageTitle());
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("showShareEarn","N");

                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            }else if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("update")) {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
                                notificationIntent.setData(Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.milmila.android.milmila_home"));
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            }else if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("home")) {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                //notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId",(bnkResponse.getLevelId()));
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            }else if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("invite")) {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, InviteEarnWebViewActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                // notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId",(bnkResponse.getLevelId()));
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("searchQuery", Constants.BASE_URL+"customerInvite/inviteEarn.html?customerId=#sharedPreferenceUserId#");
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("headerName","Invite & Earn");
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("showShareEarn","Y");
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            }else if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("share_earn")) {

                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, InviteEarnWebViewActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                // notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId",(bnkResponse.getLevelId()));
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("searchQuery",Constants.BASE_URL+"double-dhamaka.html?customerId=#sharedPreferenceUserId#");
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("headerName","Gift your friend 100");
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("showShareEarn","Y");
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            } else if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("product")) {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, ProductDetailsActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                notificationIntent.putExtra(STRING_IMAGE_PRODUCTID,(adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getLevelId()));
                                // notificationIntent.putExtra(STRING_IMAGE_PRODUCTID, levelId);
                                // notificationIntent.putExtra(STRING_IMAGE_PRODUCT_URL, "");
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            }else if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("Earnings")) {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                // notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId",(bnkResponse.getLevelId()));
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("mmcash", "Y");
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            } else if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("group")) {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, GroupProductListActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("categoryID",(adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getLevelId()));
                                // notificationIntent.putExtra("categoryID", levelId);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("categoryName", adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getGroupName());
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("limit", 10);
                                //  notificationIntent.putExtra("headerImage", promotionUrl);
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            }else if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("reseller")) {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                // notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId",(bnkResponse.getLevelId()));
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("resell", "Y");
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            } else if (adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationLevel().equalsIgnoreCase("normal")) {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, MyOrdersActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                // notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId",(bnkResponse.getLevelId()));
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            } else {
                                Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                                notificationIntent.putExtra("notificationClick","true");
                                // notificationIntent.putExtra("notifId",(bnkResponse.getLevelId()));
                                startActivity(notificationIntent);
                            }

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            Intent notificationIntent = new Intent(NotificationListActivity.this, BottomNavigationActivity.class);
                            startActivity(notificationIntent);
                        }
                        break;

                    case R.id.iv_arrow:



                            Glide.with(getApplicationContext())
                                    .load(adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationImage())
                                    .apply(new RequestOptions()
                                            .placeholder(R.drawable.no_image))
                                    .into(notification_iv);



                        if(flag==true)
                        {
                            notification_main_text.setSingleLine(true);
                            notification_main_text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                            int n1 = 1; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                            notification_main_text.setLines(n1);
                            notification_main_text.setMaxEms(12);
                            iv_arrow.setImageResource(R.mipmap.down);

                                notification_iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                            notification_sub_text.setSingleLine(true);
                            notification_sub_text.setEllipsize(TextUtils.TruncateAt.END);
                            int n = 1; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                            notification_sub_text.setLines(n);
                            flag = false;
                        }
                        else if(flag==false)
                        {
                            notification_main_text.setSingleLine(false);
                            int n1 = 2; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                            notification_main_text.setLines(n1);
                            notification_main_text.setMaxEms(10);
                            notification_main_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            iv_arrow.setImageResource(R.mipmap.up);
                            notification_sub_text.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            if(adaBankDetailsList.get(position).getNotificationImage().equals("null"))
                            {
                                notification_iv.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                notification_iv.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                            }
                            notification_sub_text.setSingleLine(false);
                            int n = 2; // the exact number of lines you want to display
                            notification_sub_text.setLines(n);
                            flag = true;
                        }
                        break;
                }


            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: init "boolean flag = true;" in your viewholder not gloabally in adapter

Comment: @android means?? i did not get

Comment: If possible please attach screenshot of your problem. If `Button` pressed for any item then the `ImageView` of that item should be Visible. Correct? And as per your code, If you `Scroll` or `Click` on another `Button` then visible `ImageView` getting hide.

Comment: @Ajay-Rlogical yes exactly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometime `Adapter` might cause position issue while scrolling the `Recyclerview`. You can achieve the same by tag your `ImageView` into the Button.

```
holder.your_button.setTag(holder.your_imageview);
holder.your_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        final ImageView selImageView = (ImageView) v.getTag();

        if(selImageView.getVisibility() == View.VISIBLE) {
           selImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
        } else {
           selImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE)
        }
    }
});
```

Above will only trigger your view of the same position. Because we have set that `ImageView` to your `Buttons` tag and targeting only that view.